# Программно сохранить все изображения с веб-страницы

Tags: php

Возможно ли написать функцию, которая сохраняет все изображения с указанной веб-страницы? В качестве аргумента указывается URL.

Необходимо чтобы изображения попали в каталог откуда запускался index.php.

Необходимо именно программное сохранение изображений, а не ручное (ПКМ > Сохранить как веб-страницу полностью).

Comment: Ответом на вопрос "Возможно ли" является - "да возможно". вам даже привели алгоритм в ответах. Под *nix есть программа wget которая может это сделать сама при запуске с определенными ключами. И думаю она далеко не одна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно.

1. Для получения самой страницы используйте `curl`.
2. Вытащите из
   полученного html все `img` тэги, их параметры URL. Для этого
   рекомендую использовать регулярные выражения.   Например, такое
   `<img[^s>]+src="(.+)">`
3. Скачайте картинки с полученных URL (можно тоже использовать
   `cURL`) и сохраните при помощи `file_put_contents`).